# Editor: single click for combobox, double click for textField

Tags: extjs, editor

I have [tree panel](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.tree.Panel.html), that has the [cell editing plugin](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing.html):

```
plugins = {
    ptype: 'cellediting',
    clicksToEdit: 1
};
```

And I want to achieve the following scenario: if there is a single click on a node, the editor should be a combobox, if double click - editor should be a textfield. How can I implement this?

This is my function from the controller:

```
getEditor: function (record) {
    if (dblclick) {
        Ext.create('Ext.grid.CellEditor', {
            field: Ext.widget('combo', {
                editable: false,
                allowBlank: false,
                flex: 1,
                queryMode: 'local',
                store: App.store.Goods,
                displayField: 'name',
                valueField: 'id'
            })
        });
    };

    if (singleClick) {
        return Ext.create('Ext.grid.CellEditor', {
            field: Ext.widget('textfield', {
                selectOnFocus: true,
                maxLength: 20,
                enforceMaxLength: true
            })
        });
    }

    return;
},
```